# Split a video having millisecond time accuracy with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to extract a part of a video with quite accurate time values. I tried following methods which were not a success.

```
ffmpeg -y -i <input_mp4> -ss 0.570 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -t 6.690000 -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -preset faster -crf 28 -acodec aac -map_metadata -1 -movflags faststart <output_mp4>
ffmpeg -y -ss 0 -i <input_mp4> -ss 0.570 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -t 6.690000 -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -preset faster -crf 28 -acodec aac -map_metadata -1 -movflags faststart <output_mp4>
ffmpeg -y -ss 0 -accurate_seek -i <input_mp4> -ss 0.570 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -t 6.690000 -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -preset faster -crf 28 -acodec aac -map_metadata -1 -movflags faststart <output_mp4>
```

In all of those commands I wanted to extract a video with duration of 6.690000 seconds, but actual resulted video was 6.712000 seconds long.
[This](http://pastebin.com/CaGPT3cr) is the uncut `FFmpeg` output.

Following is the `FFprobe` command I used to get the duration of the output video.

```
ffprobe -i <extracted_video> -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

I was referring to [seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) document for `FFmpeg`. Is there anything wrong with above commands or is there any alternative way to extract the video with accurate time duration?

- Input video framerate: 60 fps
- Input video bitrate: 25380 kbps

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/1154799/114058

Comment: @Mulvya - that answer looks correct. +1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ffmpeg: extremely precise extraction of video segments](https://superuser.com/questions/1154799/ffmpeg-extremely-precise-extraction-of-video-segments)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this SO question [ffmpeg: extremely precise extraction of video segments](https://superuser.com/questions/1154799/ffmpeg-extremely-precise-extraction-of-video-segments)
suggested by [Mulvya](https://superuser.com/users/114058/mulvya)