# ffmpeg: cut videos with millisecond accuracy without audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a similar problem to this [unanswered post](https://superuser.com/questions/1154799/ffmpeg-extremely-precise-extraction-of-video-segments/1257906?noredirect=1#comment1849456_1257906).

---

#### First try

I use this [video](http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4) file which has AAC@48000 sampling rate. I first tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4 -ss 00:00:08.781 -t 17.861 output.mp4
```

I checked the output duration with this command:

```
ffprobe -i output.mp4 -show_format -v quiet | sed -n 's/duration=//p'
```

and it returned `17.883000`

---

#### Mulvya's solution

Then I tried Mulvya's solution and tried

- To strip the audio out with `-an`
- To have an export duration equal to a multiple of `0.021333`

So here is what I tried :

```
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4 -ss 00:00:08.781 -t 17.856 -an output2.mp4
```

---

Unfortunately, the result is `17.880` and still not ok.

Does anyone know what is wrong here and have a solution ?

Comment: I didn't provide a solution in that answer, but clarified why that granularity doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, I know. It helped me indeed to understand my problem better and to get a more precise cut but it is unfortunately still not 100% accurate. Do you suggest that the kind of trim I wish is unreachable ?

Comment: If you have a framerate of 25 frames per second, then one frame takes up 1/25 = 0,04 seconds. so there's no sense in making a cut at e.g. 0.900 seconds: either use 0.880 or 0.920. It's the same with audio, by the way: a cut below the sampling rate (e.g. 48000 Hz) would not make sense.

Comment: In theory, it should be possible to adjust the duration of the last packet so as to achieve that precise value (provided the timebase provides that resolution), Don't think the CLI allows that but the API should.

Comment: You can [omit the `sed` process](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration).